# How do I disable the Dash preview?

Tags: unity-dash

I would like to have it configured so that a single click opens my folders and documents from the dash. Currently, when I single click a document or folder, it opens up some in-dash preview dialog box, forcing me to either click "open in folder" or to double-click the object to open it.

Is there any way to disable the preview option? Running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit w/ Unity 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[Found a nice article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/06/the-new-click-behaviour-in-the-dash)

Run the command `dconf-editor`. Navigate to `com - canonical - unity` and untick `double-click-activate`.

Now it will open it immediately.

Answer (score 3):

[Tim's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/485148/72576) should serve the way you want it. Also, it might be faster to use the <kbd>Return</kbd> key instead of first typing what you want and then using the mouse to click over the desired icon.

First type the name of the required application / folder and then use the navigations keys to choose and <kbd>Return</kbd> to open the application / folder. Of course, this will only be helpful when the list of returned results has few icons; otherwise it is better to use a mouse to open.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/486760/662944) input this into the terminal.

> gsettings set com.canonical.Unity double-click-activate false