# How can I enable one-click open in the unity dash?

Tags: unity, 14.04, unity-dash

Searching in the unity dash and clicking an item gives me options such as *sharing via e-mail* or *revealing the file in nautilus* which I rarely use.

I'd rather restore the behavior of 12.04 where you could open a file with just **one** click.

How can I enable click open in unity dash?

Comment: Look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/485122/disable-dash-preview-in-14-04/485148#485148

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To restore the desired behaviour,

From a command line run the following:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity double-click-activate false
```